# Store longest variable name in another temporary variable

Tags: java, arraylist

Here I am reading student data from file and storing in db.For that am using ArrayList.
For example,

```
Student(){
private int rollNo;
private String name,department,branch; 
private String cgpa;

.
.
.
public int getRollNo(){
    return rollNo;
}
public String getName(){
    return name;
}
public String getDepartment(){
    return department;
}
public String getBranch(){
    return branch;
}
public String getCgpa(){
    return cgpa;
}
```

}

and my arraylist variable is

```
ArrayList<Student> stu;
```

Inorder to access any field from arraylist,I have to use `stu.get(i).getRollNo()`,
`stu.get(i).getName()`,`stu.get(i).getDepartment()` and so on. Here I have used `stu.get(i)` multiple times. To avoid that I stored `stu.get(i)` in temporary variable. For example

```
String temp="stu.get(i)."

sql="INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('"+temp+"getRollNo()"+"','"+temp+"getName()"+"','"+temp+"getDepartment()"+"','"+temp+"getBranch()"+"',"+Float.parseFloat(temp+"getCgpa()")+")";
```

But When I use `temp+"getRollNO()"`,that method is not called. Please explain this problem. If its not possible please give me alternative way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Student s = stu.get(i);
sql = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('"+s.getRollNo()+"','"+s.getName()+"','"+s.getDepartment()+"','"+s.getBranch()+"',"+Float.parseFloat(s.getCgpa())+")";
```

The list contains students, therefore you should get a student object from the list and access the getters directly.

Comment: Prone to sql-injection, thus not recommended.

Comment: True, it is prone to sql-injection. But the error in the code had to do with this part. I agree that the PreparedStatement solution would be a better solution for safely inserting data into a database.

Answer (score 4):

The bad way to do it is to embed the values from your list into the SQL string :

```
sql="INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('"+ stu.get(i).getRollNo()+"','"+stu.get(i).getName()+"','"+...+")");
```

The correct (and safe) way to do it is to use a PreparedStatement :

```
sql="INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(?,?,?,?,...,?)";
```

Then you create a `PreparedStatement` and add the parameters with calls like :

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
ps.setString(1,stu.get(i).getRollNo());
ps.setString(2,stu.get(i).getName());
...
ps.executeUpdate ();
```

If your concern is having to fetch the Student from the list multiple times, you can change it to :

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
Student s = stu.get(i);
ps.setString(1,s.getRollNo());
ps.setString(2,s.getName());
...
ps.executeUpdate ();
```

Comment: Actually this is not my problem. stu.get(i) is used multiple times how to avoid using temporary variable like I mentioned above..

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR It is your problem, since putting "stu.get(i).getRollNo()" as a String in the sql String won't work, unless you are using some DB I don't know.

Comment: @GaneshkumarSR And if your concern is having to type `stu.get(i)` many times, you a temporary variable of type Student, but use it with a PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using

```
Student temp=stu.get(i)
temp.getRollNo() , temp.getName()
```

stu.get(i) returns an instance of type Student. You can then use this reference to access the fields in student. What you were previously doing was literally writing the value "stu.get(i).getRollNo()" to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In here, when you call stu.get(i) it is return a Student object and not a String. Therefore you have to change the reference type as Student. Do the following change,

Student temp= stu.get(i);

Good Luck !!!